# Get Symfony form data before building the form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm displaying the form on a page by doing this in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new Email(),
        ]
    ])
    ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank()
        ]
    ])
    ->add('passwordRepeat', PasswordType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new EqualTo('VALUE OF PASSWORD'),
        ]
    ])
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Reset',
    ])->getForm();

return $this->render('page/forgot-password.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView()
]);
```

The problem is that the value of the `passwordRepeat` input has to be equal to the value of the `password` input. But in order to get the data from the `password` input I already have to build the form and then I can't add the condition anymore.

How can I make sure the value of `password` can be added as to the `EqualTo` constraint in `passwordRepeat`?

Comment: You use the [`propertyPath`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/EqualTo.html#propertypath) property instead of passing a value.

Comment: @msg I read the docs in the link you provided, but I don't understand how I have to implement that in the EqealTo constraint. Can you give an example in an answer?

Comment: The usual approach is to use a [RepeatedType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html).  Takes care of some of the scut work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a value, you can use the [`propertyPath`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/EqualTo.html#propertypath) option, that allows you to reference the value of another field in your form:

```
->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank()
    ]
])
->add('passwordRepeat', PasswordType::class, [
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank(),
        new EqualTo(['propertyPath' => 'password']),
    ]
])
```